# Shopify - Adding choosable related products on product page

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am creating a new custom section and I would like to add different kind of blocks in it. But I can't find any list of the existing / available / native blocks types (block.type).

**EDIT : I was looking for available "specialized input settings" and not "block types".** [Here the related documentation](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#specialized-input-settings) !

My final goal would be to add meta field to the product entity, allowing an admin to pick a selection of products from an existing product, then to bind this meta product field, to a 'products' block type in my new custom section.

**EDIT : Added a solution in reply.**

Comment: the block type is just a valid string and unique across all blocks into sections. the main role of input type that is used inside settings, so you feel free to name block as per your requirements or purpose.

Comment: Thx for your reply, I hear you. Let me rephrase :  Is there an existing "product collection" block type ? If not how can I create one ?

Comment: you simply add a block with any name and that into settings you use type is `product`, you can check and read more about available inputs type [Shopify inputs](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings) here.

Comment: Thanks for your link this is exactly what I was looking for ! I was not using the good term (input setting vs block type), you rock !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so thanks to @Onkar and Patrick from discord, here the related documentation : https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings#specialized-input-settings

In order to do what I described above, I created a dedicated new meta field "related_product" for product entities : Backend > Settings > Metafields > Custom fields > Products (type Product : List of products).

Then I created a new section in my theme files (sections/product-related.liquid) :

```
{%- liquid
    assign grid = section.settings.per_row
-%}

{% unless section.settings.product_list == empty %}
    <div class="product-recommendations row" data-product-id="{{ product.id }}">
            <div class="section-title {% if settings.section_titles == 'lines' %}lines {% elsif settings.section_titles == 'btm_border' %}btm_border {% endif %} desktop-12 tablet-6 mobile-3">
                <h2>{{ section.settings.heading }}</h2>
            </div>
        <div class="product-loop">
            {%- for product in section.settings.product_list limit: section.settings.limit -%}
                <div class="product product-index js-product-listing">
                    {% render 'product-listing', template: 'product', product: product %}
                </div>
            {%- endfor -%}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endunless %}

{% schema %}
    {
        "name": "Related Products",
        "settings": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "heading",
                "label": "Heading",
                "default": "You may also like"
            },
            {
                "type": "product_list",
                "id": "product_list",
                "label": "Products",
                "limit": 12
            },
            {
                "type": "range",
                "id": "per_row",
                "min": 2,
                "max": 4,
                "step": 1,
                "label": "Products per row",
                "default": 4
            },
            {
                "type": "range",
                "id": "limit",
                "min": 2,
                "max": 6,
                "step": 1,
                "label": "Products shown",
                "default": 4
            }
        ],
        "presets": [
            {
                "name": "Related Products"
            }
        ],
        "templates": [
            "product"
        ]
    }
{% endschema %}

{% stylesheet %}
    .product-recommendations .product-loop {
        margin: 20px auto;
        display: grid;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 1.04166667%;
        margin-right: 1.04166667%;
        grid-template-columns: repeat({{ grid }}, 1fr);
        grid-row-gap: 25px;
        grid-column-gap: 40px;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 741px) and (max-width: 980px){
        .product-recommendations .product-loop {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 10px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 740px){
        .product-recommendations .product-loop {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-gap: 10px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    }
{% endstylesheet %}

{% javascript %}
{% endjavascript %}
```

After that I was able to add the section to my product template from Theme customisation. Last thing to do was to map / bind my custom meta field to the 'product_list' block / input. And voila !

[image]